# Android flavor - cannot find symbol variable in R file

Tags: android, r.java-file, android-productflavors

I have 2 flavors - paidapp and freeapp.
The only difference that paidapp have 1 more button on `MainActivity`, say `"paidbutton"`.
paidapp has its own layout with button `android:id="@+id/paidbutton"` and layout for freeapp does not have this button.

In code I use this:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("paidapp")) {
            View paidbutton = findViewById(R.id.paidbutton);
            paidbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //...
                }
            });
}
```

But I have an error `cannot find symbol variable` in `findViewById(R.id.paidbutton);`

How to solve this problem without cloning MainActivity.java in both flavors?

**EDIT1** - add more code examples:

Gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    paidapp {
    }
    freeapp {
    }
}
```

/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

/app/src/paidapp/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/paidbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="See more" />


</LinearLayout>
```

/app/src/main/java/company/com/myapplication/MainActivity.java

```
package company.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View goNext = findViewById(R.id.goNext);
        goNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "goNext click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("paidapp")) {
            View paidbutton = findViewById(R.id.paidbutton);
            paidbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "paidapp click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT2** - I have found some workaround using reflection, but still looking for normal solution:

instead of `View paidbutton = findViewById(R.id.paidbutton);` I have used `View paidbutton = findViewById(getIdFromRId("paidbutton"));`

where `getIdFromRId` is:

```
private int getIdFromRId(String idName) {
    int id = 0;
    try {
        Class c = R.id.class;
        Field field = c.getField(idName);
        id = field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Facing same error but this seems expected behavior because when we switch to a particular `build variant(flavor)`, that flavor specific resources are loaded up hence the IDE gives error can't find symbol. You have **two options** 1. either you put both buttons in activity_main and use one layout file from main (no need for flavor specific version) and hide/show buttons on base of flavors at run time. 2. copy your `MainActivity.java` inside both flavors!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't have `paidbutton` layout element at all in the `freeapp` product flavor, you can just declare corresponding id item in one of your resource xml files in `freeapp` product flavor folder. For example create the file `src/freeapp/res/values/ids.xml` containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="paidbutton" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

After doing that you'll have no problems with compiling common code since the symbol `R.id.paidbutton` will be defined for both product flavors. `findViewById()` call will return the real layout element in `paidapp` build and will return null in `freeapp` build.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put your paidbutton XML tag and your MainActivity.java class imports please.

You are maybe using the wrong resource import like `import android.R;` instead of `import my_package.R;`

Comment: I do not have import R in imports

Comment: Where your function is in the code? Before or after the setContentView() method? Compilator cannot find the R symbol because you are trying to use it before his initialization.

Comment: Compilator can find R, but in R file there are no R.id.paidbutton for freeapp flavor and exist R.id.paidbutton for paidapp flavor. Thats why paidapp flavor assambled successfully but freeapp flavor not successfully.

Comment: Well, on your Java exemple,  you are not using your proper R claas. Add this import : "import company.com.myapplication.R"

Comment: R file located in the same package as my MainActivity, so I do not need to import it. In any case, your advice does not help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I seems to me that you do not really understand the problem. I have 2 R files simultaneously with package company.com.myapplication.R, in one file I have R.id.paidbutton and in another - don't have. When I use import company.com.myapplication.R it will import both files simultaneously.

Comment: I think you'll be force to clone your code (like 2 library). See that page: [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts)

Answer (score 1):

You need your if clause in the on create and then add the setContentView, so somethin like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("paidapp")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_paid);
        View paidbutton = findViewById(R.id.paidbutton);
        paidbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //...
            }
        });
}
else{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_free);
}
```

or you could possibly use one layout for both and just make the button invisible

I hope this helps

Comment: Why do i need activity_main_paid and activity_main_paid? I have just activity_main in both flavors

Comment: these are just the different layouts, you only use one mainactivity, and in there you decide which layout you want to use

Comment: Looks like it will work, but it kill flavors idea with different sourceSets, I should care about which xml will be chousen manually instead of androidPlugin