# Why do I get an error: cannot find symbol variable in R class

Tags: java, android, r.java-file, cannot-find-symbol

The following source code should make a picture and display it on the screen. But I get some errors. `Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_fullscreen'`, the same for `imageView1`, `dummy_button`, `fullscreen_content` and `fullscreen_content_controls`.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);//dummy abaendern


        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    }
```

Those are my imports:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.R;
```

Now let us have a look at the `activity_fullscreen.xml` The missing parts are definitely there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.example.sasha.myapplication2.FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I already checked the recommendations in [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean).
As far as I can see the names does not contain any illegal characters. I also already restarted the android studio going by  File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..

But I still did not find any solution to my problems. How is it posible that R can be resolved but not its content? Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312897/android-flavor-cannot-find-symbol-variable-in-r-file)?

Comment: Why is this helpful?I only have one Button and one ItemView

Comment: You're calling `findViewById(R.id.some_name_here);`

Comment: I don't really understand your point. What do I need to change?

Comment: Because of you import `android.R`, you should remove it, clean project. Press Alt + Enter to import right library `yourpackage.R`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported the wrong 'R'

Remove this :

```
import android.R;
```

Add this :

```
import com.yourCompany.yourApp.R;
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Although eclipse marks the import as unused it seems to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this to import the mapping of your app.

```
  import com.example.sasha.myapplication2.R;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import the R File. This will remove the casting of R.Activity file. Clean the project to remove the error.